# Dynamically adding UIButton to UITableViewCell error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I use following code to adding a UIButton to UITableViewCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  MainCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MainCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

  self.btnMessage = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 54, 15)];
  [self.btnMessage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.btnMessage addTarget:self action:@selector(messageButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.btnMessage setTitle:@"Message" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  self.btnMessage.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
  [self.btnMessage setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 0)];
  [cell addSubview:self.btnMessage];

  return cell;
}
```

everything is ok when i run this code, but if i scroll the table, the button will add again and again in each cell, like superimposed or each cell has some same buttons superimposed, so how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Move the code to add the button inside the `if (cell == nil)` statement. This will ensure that the button is only added to new cells, not dequeued cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  MainCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MainCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    self.btnMessage = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 54, 15)];
    [self.btnMessage setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnMessage addTarget:self action:@selector(messageButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.btnMessage setTitle:@"Message" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.btnMessage.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    [self.btnMessage setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 12, 0, 0)];
    [cell addSubview:self.btnMessage];
  }

  return cell;
}
```